# Mounting an S3 bucket using goofys inside container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, goofys

I am writing a Dockerfile and my hope is to have S3 buckets mounted using goofys. If I run my docker container in interactive mode I can easily mount a S3 bucket with the following line

```
goofys --region=us-west -f s3_bucket mount_point &
```

However when I include this line in my Dockerfile the S3 bucket never gets mounted.

Comment: What is the output of `docker build` when it fails at `goofys` command.

Comment: It actually doesn't fail, it successfully builds. However when I run the docker container in interactive mode the bucket is not mounted.

Comment: How are you including this command in your Dockerfile?